# preventDefault not blocking keys that use Alt modifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that occasionally prevents all keyboard inputs from reaching the webpage temporarily (as the extension's handler performs its own tasks with the keyboard inputs that it catches). And the extension does a good job listening to all of those inputs.

HOWEVER, some keyboard inputs still get through the webpage! Specifically, certain keyboard inputs that use the Alt modifier key reach the webpage. I have replicated the issue with this code:

```
$(window).get(0).addEventListener("keypress",
    function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
}, true);
```

You can interact with the code in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Sophtware/5ucefew2/

Can someone help me figure out why this is happening and how to fix it?

EDIT #1: I found out that the symbols that are coming through the preventDefault call are things like accents or other "combining characters" (like ´, ˆ, ¨). In fact, once a combining character has been typed, the next character typed will always also fail to be blocked.

Comment: See my answer below for several issues you have and a working example.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, you didn't have jQuery loaded in your Fiddle.

Second, you need to use the `keydown` event, not `keypress` because `keypress` doesn't fire when keys that don't produce visible characters are pressed. This is why you found that some characters work with it and others don't.

Third, your event binding code isn't really written correctly. There is no need to use `get(0)` when jQuery returns a wrapped set that contains only one item. And since there is only one `window` or `document`, that code isn't needed.

Additionally, you can check explicitly for the ALT key being pressed.

Lastly, please don't post your code to 3rd party sites because those links can become broken over time. Instead post your code snippets right here.

See comments inline:

```js
// Set the event on the document, but then test for the input element when it happens
$(document).on("keydown", "input[type='text']", function(e){
  // Check the event for the ALT key press
  console.log("Keystroke cancelled!");
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>
Type in Alt + 'e', Alt + 'i', or other Alt combinations! They get typed in even though they're not supposed to!
</h3>
<p>
Strangely, Alt+j and Alt+k cannot be written more than once in a row and act strange in general.

If you type in Alt + e and then a regular letter key press, the letter gets typed! ??????
</p>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: I ran your code and it blocks even less keyboard events than my code. It doesn't block the Alt + 'e' combination or any of the other Alt combinations. It doesn't block regular keystrokes either. Again, I am trying to have code that blocks ALL keyboard inputs. My problem is that my code blocks only MOST keyboard inputs.

Comment: @Sophtware You are mistaken. Did you run my code snippet posted right here or did you copy my code into your project? Again, your Fiddle didn't have jQuery included, so none of that code was running at all. My code blocks any key combinations that begin with ALT. I will update the question to prevent all keystrokes.

Comment: I have clicked "Run code snippet" and then typed into the input box <Alt> + 'e' and an accent gets typed.

Comment: @Sophtware Did you try my (just updated) code? I was mistakenly under the impression that you wanted to cancel any keystrokes that began with the pressing of the actual ALT key. The current code cancels all input. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome 59. I just tried your code again and the accent still gets typed when you type <Alt> + 'e' together. I am holding down the Alt key and then I press 'e' and then an accent gets typed. Does the accent not get typed for you?

Comment: @Sophtware I too am using Chrome 59 and (as expected) absolutely nothing is typed when any key at all is typed. Also, you are confusing me. If you are talking about the actual ALT key, please don't type it as <Alt> because that implies you really mean that the < and > should be typed. The convention is just to capitalize like: ALT + e

Comment: I just realized that this may be something that only happens with macbooks. Are you using a mac?

Comment: @Sophtware No. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: @Sophtware I am facing the same problem with alt+e - the accented char is still appearing. Did you figure out why this is happening and how to work around it?

Comment: I have ran this snippet on Window 7 64bit and in Chrome fails on preventing Dead keys, but in Firefox it prevents perfectly.